# How to react to a specific style attribute change with mutation observers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mutation-observers

I've been experimenting with Mutation Observers, so far I can apply the relevant functions to react upon adding, removing elements and so on. Now I am wondering, is there a way to target a specific change within a specific style attribute? I know I can observe for attribute changes, but I just don't know how to observe for a specific attribute modification. For example, if the z-index value of #childDiv changes to 5678, modify the style of the parentDiv in order for it to be shown.

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div id="childDiv" style="z-index:1234;">
    MyDiv
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There seems to be an `attributeFilter` option you can pass in to find a specific attribute. Obviously it will trigger for any change inside of the style attribute, because the value is not special to the MutationObserver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) use `attributeFilter` array and list the HTML attributes, `'style'` here:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(styleChangedCallback);
observer.observe(document.getElementById('childDiv'), {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style'],
});

var oldIndex = document.getElementById('childDiv').style.zIndex;

function styleChangedCallback(mutations) {
    var newIndex = mutations[0].target.style.zIndex;
    if (newIndex !== oldIndex) {
        console.log('new:', , 'old:', oldIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this still triggers on *any* style, not the specific one desired!

Comment: @Michael, of course: there's only one `style` *attribute*, which is an exact term in the DOM specification. There are no observers for CSSOM accessors so you'll need to perform the comparison of the old and new values yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for offtop.
Conception React is no mutations. If you need to listen some changes of some element (style for example). You can use `componentDidUpdate` and get element from `@refs.parentDiv` (set ref before this in render function `<div id="parentDiv" ref="parentDiv" style="display:none;">`) and after check style and set you z-Index value before new render.

Comment: +1 for good advice. break those anti patterns and get reactive. then you can truly learn once and write anywhere. Good luck and God bless