# Listening to DOM events (specific attributes)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I need to get data when a specific attribute is added .
I have read this post : [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)

```
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
     $.each(mutations, function(index, mutation) {

      var post = $(mutation.target).find('div[class^="ContentWrapper"]');


     });
  });
  observer.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true

  });
```

There is a problem with this approach because there are to many events and the extension is very slow,is there an option to filter the mutations,by specific attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to react to a specific style attribute change with mutation observers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024163/how-to-react-to-a-specific-style-attribute-change-with-mutation-observers)

Comment: this is not good....it will give me all the added class's,i want a specific class   @wOxxOm

Comment: This is the only method to limit attribute observation. Be creative. Don't observe the entire document, do it on the parent container, for example.

Comment: Also NEVER use jQuery and other monster wrappers in a mutation observer, switch to direct DOM access: `for (var i=0; ....) { var post=mutations[i].target.getElementsByClassName('ContentWrapper')[0]; ...... }`

Comment: Alternatively, if you can observe the immediate parent element for added nodes (and then attach another observer to watch for attribute on each of those added nodes) then you won't need `subtree: true,` so your observer will be super fast even with jQuery.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, especially for bringing up not using jquery!

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you !! for the explanation

Comment: [MutationSummary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) Could help you. Give it a target and it will give you a summary of everything that's happened (within reason). I.e. A summary of DOM Events/Mutation Events. Hope it helps. There's an example on the github of it's use.

Answer (score 6):

Use `attributeFilter` in the MutationObserverInit options. Set it to an array of attributes that you want to listen for like so:

```
var attributeSpecificObserver=new MutationObserver(function_you_want_observing);
attributeSpecificObserver.observe( element_you_want_to_observe, {
    attributeFilter: ['id', 'class', 'style', 'etc'],
} );
```

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit).

Comment: apparently if you want to only not listen to a few attributes you must manually filter them out?

Comment: Yes, `attributeFilter` is opt-in, not opt-out.