# My script is working on the chrome console, but not in TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Currently I am working on a script that adds two buttons: one that says "Office 2013" and one that says "Office 2019". The script works fine when I go into Chrome Inspect => Sources and paste the script, but when I try to use the script via Tampermonkey I don't have any luck.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SNIPEIT OFFICE BUTTONS
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match      my url was here 
// @grant        none
// @run-at document-body
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';


    //  let p = document.getElementById("notes");

 const notes = document.querySelector("#create-form > div > div.box-body > div > div:nth-child(10) > div");

    // p.appendChild(btn2013);

    function addOffice2013() {
        let btn2013 = document.createElement("button");
        btn2013.innerHTML = "Office 2013 TM";
        btn2013.onclick = () => {
            alert("hello");
        notes.appendChild(btn2013);
        }
    }


    let btn2019 = document.createElement("button");
    btn2019.innerHTML = "Office 2019 TM";
    btn2019.onclick = () => {
        alert("hello");
    }

    //p.appendChild(btn2019);

    addOffice2013();
    // notes.appendChild(btn2013);
});
```

I've tried changing the settings so the script loads when the DOM is fully loaded, but that didn't work. I tried setting it up as a function, that didn't work. I double checked the query selector paths as well.

Comment: Perhaps the element you're selecting using `document.querySelector()` appears *after* the document has loaded. Try waiting until it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this - it could be that (even using `@run-at document-body`) the DOM might not be fully extant when the JavaScript is executed - meaning that the `#create-form` HTML scaffolding might not be fully present, causing the `querySelector()` line to fail.

Try it like this, and then reduce the value of var `myDelay` until it is as low as feasible.  If this works, then you really should try to switch away from the setTimeout solution to using a [mutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024295/1447509):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SNIPEIT OFFICE BUTTONS
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match      my url was here 
// @grant        none
// @run-at document-body
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    myDelay = 5000;      //<===== ADDED THIS
    setTimeout( () => {  //<===== ADDED THIS

       //  let p = document.getElementById("notes");

       const notes = document.querySelector("#create-form > div > div.box-body > div > div:nth-child(10) > div");

       // p.appendChild(btn2013);

       function addOffice2013() {
           let btn2013 = document.createElement("button");
           btn2013.innerHTML = "Office 2013 TM";
           btn2013.onclick = () => {
               alert("hello");
               notes.appendChild(btn2013);
           }
       }


       let btn2019 = document.createElement("button");
       btn2019.innerHTML = "Office 2019 TM";
       btn2019.onclick = () => {
           alert("hello");
       }

       //p.appendChild(btn2019);

       addOffice2013();
       // notes.appendChild(btn2013);

    }, myDelay);  //<===== ADDED THIS
});
```